# Prove that $(2^{a} -1, 2^{b} -1) = 2^{(a,b)} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are any two natural numbers, then
$$(2^{a} -1, 2^{b} -1) = 2^{(a,b)} - 1$$

The proof goes something like this. Let $a = bq + r$, where $0\leq r < b)$, then note that
$$x^a-1 = (x^b-1)(x^{a-b} + ... + x^{a-bq}) + x^r - 1$$
In particular, setting $x = 2$ yields:
$$2^a - 1 = (2^b-1)Q + 2^r - 1$$. Hence
$$(2^a - 1, 2^b - 1) = (2^b - 1, 2^r-1)$$
From here, it is supposedly obvious that the chain of equalities in Euclid's algorithm $$(a,b) = (b,r) = ... = (d,0) = d $$ is exactly matched by the chain
$$(2^a - 1, 2^b - 1) = (2^b -1, 2^r - 1) = ... = (2^d -1, 0) = 2^d -1 $$

Is the idea that if $(a,b) = (b,r) = d$ and $(f(a), f(b)) = (f(b), f(r))$, then $(f(a), f(b)) = f(d)$?

Comment: No, there is no "$f$" here. Simply the fact (used repeatedly) that if $a=bq+r$ then $2^a-1=(2^b-1)Q+(2^r-1)$ (where $Q=2^{a-b} + ... + 2^{a-bq}$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Sure, it's the last step I'm struggling with, I don't see how $(2^b - 1, 2^r -1) = (2^d-1, 0)$ follows from that?

Comment: You are using this *repeatedly*. I.e. you have a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n=a_{n+1}q_n+a_{n+2}$ hence $2^{a_n}-1=(2^{a_{n+1}}-1)Q_n+(2^{a_{n+2}}-1)$ and at the end, $a_{m+1}=0$ so (going backwards) $\gcd$ of any two consecutive $a_n$s is $a_m$ and $\gcd$ of any two consecutive $(2^{a_n}-1)$s is $2^{a_m}-1$.

Comment: @Anne OP means $\,f(n) = 2^n-1\,$ so "there *is* an '$f\,$' here", and OP's idea is correct.

Comment: @OnlyStupidQuestions Are you ok now?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I got it now!